# Efficiency: 8 arrays vs a multidimensional array

Tags: c, pic, microchip

What is more efficient? 8 arrays `int8 myArrayx[100]`, or a multidimensional `int8 myArray[8][100]`? I'm working with CCS compiler for Microchip PIC microcontrollers, and I need to write as fast as possible in a buffer, that is the reason of my question.

Comment: Why don't you try writing the way it seems most natural and then decide if it needs improvement ?

Comment: For speed, use a pointer to the array element that just needs an increment or addition for each successive access, rather than an index myArray[i] style which requires a multiplication.

Comment: If you want to use a PIC and get performance avoid C at all costs.  The pic itself is slow enough.  The answer to your question is try both and disassemble and look at what is being generated.  PIC or any platform.  With the PIC you can count cycles, other platforms take more work and knowledge to study the assembly, so for your platform you can see the performance difference just by looking.  There is no one universal answer to your question other than: "it depends..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would have to think that the multi-dimensional array would be faster. you have a much, much better chance (possibly guaranteed?) of having those arrays being placed into memory in contiguous space whereas you can not be sure that the 8 individual arrays will be "close" together in memory - hurting your locality of reference.

Comment: locality in a PIC with a synchronous memory system?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which items you would access the most.
But likely it doesn't really matter. Only difference is the underlaying memory map allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how the arrays are allocated. If on the heap, then a single multidim. array would be faster for many purposes due to locality of reference and you can allocate the array in one go, which is simpler and incurs less overhead.

If on the stack or `static`, the actual binary code produced might be exactly the same.

(I'm not sure you actually have a heap in your device, but I thought I'd mention it anyway ;)